# correct store structure when an action has child that needs to be retrieved with an action/api

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm really new to react and I have a structure question...

I have the following structure:

```
cases:{
   isFetching(pin):false,
   isReady(pin):true,
   errorMessage(pin):"",
   list:{
      0:{
        id: "f8628ec8-5eRc-4d95-epj2-189ed8da",
        userId(pin):"189ed8da-eff2-4d95-a76d-6fc794aa2bce"
        name: "james",
        photos:{
           0:{},
           1:{
             userId(pin):"189ed8da-eff2-4d95-a76d-6fc794aa2bce"
             timestamp(pin):"2016-07-20T15:32:59.034+0000"
             id(pin):"b9628ec8-2efc-471c-8c84-16a7125d131e"
           }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I retrieve the cases list with an action and store it in the react store, now eace one of the cases has a list of photos that the filePath needs to be retrieved and stored with a separate action/api.

Is it more correct to call filePaths action/api call separate completely form the cases action and store the result of the filePaths separate.
Or it could be a part of the cases action and stored as a child of a case photo? (meaning that I'll be able to do state.cases.list[0].photo[0].filePath).

what is the best way todo it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct We should try to avoid multiple API calls /requests as far as possible

Just do

```
 state.cases.list[0].photo[0].filePath
```

to get your file parth